# Handling a sequence of clicks with javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick, onclicklistener, buttonclick

When using plain javascript to handle the clicking of a button, I have the following problem.

I have generic code like this:

```
let count = 0
myButton.onclick = function() {
    if (count > 2 {
        ... do something special ...
        // This does not work!!
    }
    ...
    count++
}
```

It is basically working, but I want to be able to make the difference between the first click and the second, third ..etc..

I would only need to have some kind of variable starting with the value 0 (for instance) and getting incremented on each click.

What is the correct way to implement such a variable?

What instinctively came to mind at this point (roughly 2 solutions) has failed.

Comment: could you also share the solution that failed? I would say to save a count variable on the window object or in the localStorage/sessionStorage according to your usecase

Comment: I modified the post to include one of the solutions I tried. The other one was using a <div id='counter'>1</div> (in the HTML) that I tried to access with document.getElementById but all failed. How do you use the localStorage/sessionStorage (or the window object) that you mention?

Answer (score 0):

You should increment the count before `if` condition then it will give you your desired result. Your code will also work but on 4th click, this will give you a better idea of how it is working:

```js
var count = 0
myButton = document.getElementById("mybutton");
myButton.onclick = function() {
  console.log('Initial Count is', count);
    if (count > 2) { //This is checking if initial count is > 2
        console.log("Executed");
    }
    count++;
    console.log('Incremented Count is', count);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="header"></h1>
    <button id="mybutton">Click</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For some reason your code works as expected. But when used in my case (where I have a page written on the fly from a js script it does not work (the variable value is lost from one click to the next), but I solved the issue using a window object.

Comment: use `var` instead of `let`

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Add" />
<script>
var x = 0;
let btn_element = document.getElementById("myButton");

btn_element.onclick = () => {
     if(x>2)    
    {
      console.log("Task is performed", x);   
    }           
     x++;
    
};
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).